# Tracing simple recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

I am getting closer to debunking this recursive mystery, there is only one thing left that I can not trace in this line of the code, and that is the final return value wich is `243` if i call `rec()` passing it the value 5. this should be the trace:

```
n: 4 *3: 12
n: 3 *3: 9
n: 2 *3: 6
n: 1 *3: 3
n: 0 *3: 0
n: 1 *3: 3

result: 243
```

Correct? how does it get the result of 243?

```
int rec(int n)
{
if (n == 0)
    return 1;


return 3 * rec(n-1);
}
```

Comment: This effectively calculates `3^x`.

Comment: @JanDvorak overseen that. Fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function computes : **3^n**.

The number 3 is multiplied with the result of the n-1 calls.

**f(n)** = 3 * **f(n-1)**;

**f(0)** = 1;

**f(1)** = 3 * **f(0)** = 3 * 1 = 3;

**f(2)** = 3 * **f(1)** = 3 * 3 = 9;

**f(3)** = 3 * **f(2)** = 3 * 3 * **f(1)** = 3 * 3 * 3 = 27

.
.
.

**f(5)** = 3 * 3 * 3 *3 * 3 = **243**

Comment: `f(1)` should be `3*f(0) = 3*1`, not `3`.

Comment: @melpomene if someone does not understand that f(0)=1 I think recursion is the least of his problems :).

Answer (score 2):

This function computes

`3^n where n >= 0`

If you pass 5 it computes 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * (1) = 243

Answer (score -1):

It does only multipling on 3, four times:

```
return 3 * rec(n-1);
```

I think you wanted something like this:

```
return n * rec(n-1);
```

Comment: What makes you think this is the desire?

Comment: I have put 3 there just so I can study how the recursive algorithm works and calculates it´s result

Comment: So you're saying that instead of `return n * rec(n-1);` he wants `return n * rec(n-1);`? I think that's not what _you_ want to say.

Comment: I'm updating several times before final variant, sorry

Comment: Now that your recommendation is correctly different than the original code, see @JanDvorak's comment... what makes you think the OP desires a factoral function?